# US tax law for working remotely abroad

Tags: united-states, employment, illinois

I'm working in an American tech company in Illinois. Recently I traveled abroad and am working remotely for 3 months (I'm a green card holder).

Are there any tax laws in this case? Shall I report it?

Comment: I used to work for an American tech company, and many of my colleagues worked in foreign branches for several months at a time. The company had experts who provided help with income taxes for both the US and the foreign country. Check with your employer.

Answer (score 3):

The main tax law is that you have to pay income taxes on your income even when you're in a foreign country. You may also be subject to income tax requirements in the foreign country, so that depends on local law and the existence of tax treaties between the US and that country (which will also involve details of the employer, employment and why you are in that country). For example, if you're working for a solely-US company (not e.g. Amazon) and go to Norway for 3 months "working holiday", just doing your job online in a different country while skiing, you almost certainly would not have any Norwegian tax liability. It just depends on the specifics.

Comment: Tnx. Would there be any state tax deductions?